# Accessing a local js variable in razor block

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to write razor code inside javascript where I am trying to use a local variable inside the razor code. Here is the sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

for (i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
     $("#member-table tbody").append("<tr>");

     var id = data.result[i].MemberId;

     var actions = $("<td>" + @Html.ActionLink("Detay", "Edit", new { id })  + "</td>)");
}
</script>
```

the problem is that `id` is not recognized by the razor code (i.e. it does not exist in the current context). How can I achieve that ? Is there any way ?

Comment: is this loop executed only once when the page is loaded or is it used to populate dynamic content?

Comment: @EduardoWada it populates dynamic content

Answer (score 3):

**It's not possible to access a javascript variable in a razor block.**

That's because razor is executed in the server, and javascript is executed in the browser.

However, by looking at your code it seems like you are using javascript to populate a table and that's bad, there are two patterns for solving this problem, one that solves everything in the server, and another one that solves everything in the browser.

1. Solving everything in the server:

If you decide that you want to solve everything in the server, your javascript should request the contents from the server and load them into a placeholder without changing them, something like:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $("#myDinamicDiv").load("/Path/ToView");
});
```

and then you use razor's foreach loop to generate the table's html:

```
@foreach (var x in ViewBag.MyData)
{
    <tr>
         <td>Generate contents here, including links </td>
    </tr>
}
```

2. Solving everything in the client:

As pointed out in another answer, if you are using the default routing, you can just create direct strings in the javascript code and add them to your page, keep in mind however, that when using this solution, as your page gets complex, your javascript will became less and less maintainable, having a for loop that iterates over data is a sign that maybe you can benefit from javascript UI frameworks like [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) and [Knockout.js](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), in fact, what you are doing is the core of Knockout.js's third lesson in its tutorial (Single page applications)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using default routing, then simply just don't bother with the Razor @Html.ActionLink. Stick with an explicit  tag:

```
var actions = $('<td><a href="/[your-controller-here]/Edit/'+ escape(id) + '">Detay</a></td>');
```

...obviously with whatever your current controller name is substituted for [your-controller-here].

(And I'm assuming your 'id' isn't necessarily URL-encoded, hence the 'escape'.)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing server side and client side here. You cannot create @Html.ActioLink using client side variables. Html.ActionLink is rendered on the server, it does not have any clue at all about your client side variables.

If you want to use a client side variable, like "id", render a plain html link (a) tag.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me once

```
    if ('@ViewBag.DownloadLink' != '') {
        window.location.href = '@ViewBag.DownloadLink';
    }
```